# How to use High Charts with AJAX + SpringMVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, charts, highcharts

I've developed a dashboard with some charts in SpringMVC project. I used [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com)  for develop charts.
 Basically i checked so their documentations to create this chart with **AJAX + SpringMVC** but i couldn't. so basically i have get data with ajax request and create hidden table in jsp and retrieve data  from that table and generated the chart. But i want to know is how to do this data retrieving directly through AJAX request.

This is my current code

```
function chartGeneration(chart_source){
    $('#chart-space').html("");
    var chartsource = chart_source;
    $('#chart-space').highcharts(
                    {
                        data : {
                            table : document.getElementById(chartsource)
                        },
                        chart : {
                            type : 'pie'
                        },
                        title : {
                            text : ''
                        },
                        yAxis : {
                            allowDecimals : false,
                            title : {
                                text : 'Transactions'
                            }
                        },
                        tooltip : {
                            formatter : function() {
                                return '<b>' + this.series.name
                                        + '</b><br/>' + this.point.y + ' '
                                        + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
                            }
                        }
                    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function chartGeneration(chart_source) {
    $('#chart-space').html("");
    var chartsource = chart_source;
    $('#chart-space').highcharts({
        series: chart_source,
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            title: {
                text: 'Transactions'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
            }
        }
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'AJAXURL',
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            chartGeneration(data);
        }
    });
});
```